# Curious type error in java generics

Tags: java, generics

I've encountered a strange issue with the following code (well, not *exactly* this code):

```
public class CompilationProblems1 {

  static Box<Class<? extends AlcoholicBewerage>> brokenBoxOfOneBeer = boxOf(Beer.class);
  static Box<? extends Class<? extends AlcoholicBewerage>> boxOfOneBeer = boxOf(Beer.class);
  static Box<Class<? extends AlcoholicBewerage>> boxOfBeerAndVodka = boxOf(Beer.class, Vodka.class);

  interface AlcoholicBewerage {}

  class Beer implements AlcoholicBewerage {}

  class Vodka implements AlcoholicBewerage {}

  static class Box<T> {}

  static <E> Box<E> boxOf(E e) {
      return new Box<E>();
  }

  static <E> Box<E> boxOf(E e1, E e2) {
      return new Box<E>();
  }
}
```

The first declaration `brokenBoxOfOneBeer` gives a compilation error:

```
found   : lt.tool.CompilationProblems1.Box<java.lang.Class<lt.tool.CompilationProblems1.Beer>>
required: lt.tool.CompilationProblems1.Box<java.lang.Class<? extends   lt.tool.CompilationProblems1.AlcoholicBewerage>>
static Box<Class<? extends AlcoholicBewerage>> brokenBoxOfOneBeer = boxOf(Beer.class);
```

This error happens on OpenJDK 6, Eclipse and IntelliJ. I understand that it's a limitation of the type inferencer.

In the third case (`boxOfBeerAndVodka`) the compiler is able to inference the correct covariant type because it has two subtypes to choose from, I believe. But why isnt' the compiler able to compile the first declaration, but is OK with the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why isnt' the compiler able to compile the first declaration, but is OK with the second one?

In both cases, the expression `boxOf(Beer.class)` has type `Box<Class<Beer>>`.

- The first declaration needs it to have type `Box<Class<? extends AlcoholicBewerage>>`; since `Box<Class<Beer>>` isn't a subtype of `Box<Class<? extends AlcoholicBewerage>>`, this doesn't work. (`Class<Beer>` is a subtype of `Class<? extends AlcoholicBewerage>`, but due to invariance, this does *not* entail that `Box<Class<Beer>>` is a subtype of `Box<Class<? extends AlcoholicBewerage>>`.)
- The second declaration needs it to have type `Box<? extends Class<? extends AlcoholicBewerage>>` — which it does. `Class<Beer>` is a subtype of `Class<? extends AlcoholicBewerage>`, ergo `Box<Class<Beer>>` is a subtype of `Box<? extends Class<? extends AlcoholicBewerage>>`.

That is, the exact same thing is happening in your declarations as would happen in:

```
List<Object> foo = new ArrayList<String>(); // doesn't work
List<? extends Object> bar = new ArrayList<String>(); // works
```

It just looks more complicated because instead of `Object` and `String` you have another level of generic types.

Comment: Thanks. It's quite obvious when you think about it, not so much when the actual type signatures are even more complex than in the example :)

Answer (score 1):

Type arguments are inferred based on actual arguments (`Beer.class`) first ([§15.12.2.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7)). If a type argument could not be inferred based on actual arguments, the context (`brokenBoxOfBeer`) is taken into consideration ([§15.12.2.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.8)).

Thus, you can work around this issue as follows.

```
static <X, E extends X> Box<X> boxOf(E e) {
  return new Box<X>();
}
```

**Edit**: I should note that this is a work-around and comes with its own set of problems. Nested invocations will no longer be inferred correctly.

```
Box<Box<Integer>> x = boxOf(boxOf(1)); // won't compile
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I've approved ruakh's answer as it actually answers my question.